# W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting:

> "W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied error"

In Android Studio when running my app. Following is my Firebase rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me with the required change or update in code.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

to

```
allow read, write;
```

You can allow users to read from your database only when you decide that those informations can be public. If you have sensitive information (i.e. user informations), it's mandatory to **secure** your database and allow only the users you that you decide that can read that informations. So if you decide later to add authentication, then it's a must to secure your database. That's the same regarding writting purposes.